# Imprimir Fecha dateTime

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo este codigo en c# y al momento de imprimir la Fecha me lo imprime de la siguiente forma

**SALIDA**
martes, 20 de febrero de 2018

y quiero que me lo imprima de esta manera

**SALIDA**

Fecha:190301

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.cost();
        this.consM();
        this.consN();

        txtResultado.Text = Convert.ToString(vocal)+ Convert.ToString(vocaL)+ Convert.ToString(Vocal_)+ dateTimePicker1.Text;

        dateTimePicker1.Format= DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yy/MM/dd";

    }
```

Comment: ¿dateTimePicker1 es del tipo DateTime?

Answer (score -1):

Puedes hacer

`string fecha;
fecha = datetimepicker1.value.tostring("yyMMdd");`